# A place for helpful comment templates?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I often find the need to have a comment template saved for future use, say when indicating to an asker that they need to write equations in MathJax instead of attaching them as images (with links to relevant meta threads on using MathJax), or trying to get them to improve a question asked with the homework-and-exercises tag by linking to the policy on homework and check-my-work style questions without flagging their question (where I believe the question can be improved to fit inside the scope of Phys.SE).

Could we have a meta post, or an FAQ page, with a few helpful comment templates for new users? I know a few users have comment templates saved somewhere, and I often simply hunt for the relevant comment in my own comment history, but a canonical location for comment templates that most people would prefer will simplify things somewhat, especially for new users.

Comment: Canned comments are [somewhat controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372945/lets-talk-about-my-canned-comments-for-bad-questions-by-new-contributors/372973#372973).

Answer (score 24):

I use the [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) userscript with the following comments:

> **Too broad**
>
> Please only ask *one question per post* — only ask several if they are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to split them up since they cannot reasonably be answered separately. That way, answerers that might be able to answer one question but not the others still can provide useful, complete answers to a question.

> **Homework-like/check-my-work**
>
> Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

> **Too little information**
>
> It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

> **Relevant question information in link**
>
> It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

> **Link-only answer**
>
> Please do not post links without at least a basic summary of what they contain and how that content answers the question, since link-only answers become useless if the link [rots away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Link-only answers are [not considered answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/50583) here and will be deleted.

> **Homework answer**
>
> I'm deleting this in accordance with [our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583). Please do not give complete or near-complete answers to homework-like questions.

> **MathJax, not pictures**
>
> Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

> **Text, not pictures**
>
> Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

> **Good question titles**
>
> Please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583)

If you too want to use these comments, you can copy the following source directly into the import/export menu of the script:

```
###[Q] Too broad
Please only ask *one question per post* — only ask several if they are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to split them up since they cannot reasonably be answered separately. That way, answerers that might be able to answer one question but not the others still can provide useful, complete answers to a question.

###[Q] Homework-like/check-my-work
Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

###[Q] Too little information
It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

###[Q] Relevant question information in link
It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

###[A] Link-only answer
Please do not post links without at least a basic summary of what they contain and how that content answers the question, since link-only answers become useless if the link [rots away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Link-only answers are [not considered answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/50583) here and will be deleted.

###[A] Homework answer
I'm deleting this in accordance with [our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583). Please do not give complete or near-complete answers to homework-like questions.

### MathJax, not pictures
Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

### Text, not pictures
Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

###[Q] Good question titles
Please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583)
```